# A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying Ehcache

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, ehcache, second-level-cache

Hibernate 3.3.x, ehcache 2.2.x

> > The following error occurs, when I try to publish a lots of users in a single go. Any idea on why this would happen and how to rectify this? Is there a way to disable this cache prior to bulk loading of users, if so how should I do that?

```
17:17:50,140 WARN [AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy] Cache
persistence.unit:unitName=my.ear/my-ejb-1.0.0.jar#my.com.mycompany.User.phones Key com.mycompany.User.phones#9915 Lockable : null

A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying Ehcache.
If this happens regularly you should consider increasing the cache timeouts and/or capacity limits
```

EDIT1:

This error happens when I try to bulk load a lot of users into the database via JPA calls. I don't shutdown the cache manager via a tear down hook.

Answer (score 2):

From the description it looks like the second-level cache for your entities are getting full, and some of them are getting evicted from the underlying ehcache prematurely. Do you `flush` & `clear` the hibernate `Session` periodically during your bulk-insert, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts)?

Comment: To test out the hypothesis, you can try set EhCache's `maxElementsInMemory` to 0 - so that no entry ever gets evicted - and check if the warning goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at using a [Stateless Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).  If not, as @Binil Thomas mentioned, you're going to have to `flush` and `clear` your session to free up resources.

Answer (score 0):

Increase maxElementsInMemory to 0. For more reference [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576939/problems-with-a-soft-locked-cache-entry-was-expired-by-the-underlying-ehcache)

Comment: "increase to 0" doesn't make any sense